# Flask unit test throws SQLAlchemy DetachedInstanceError

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

This is my flask unit test setup, I launch an `app_instance` for all tests and rollback for each function to make sure the test DB is fresh and clean.

```
@fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def app_instance():
    app = setup_test_app()
    create_test_user_records()
    return app

@commit_test_data
def create_test_user_records():
    db.session.add_all([Test_1, Test_2, Test_3])


@fixture(scope="function", autouse=True)
def enforce_db_rollback_for_all_tests():
    yield
    db.session.rollback()

def commit_test_data(db_fn):
    @functools.wraps(db_fn)
    def wrapper():
        db_fn()
        db.session.commit()

    return wrapper
```

They work quite well until one day I want to add an API test.

```
def test_admin(app_instance):
    test_client = app_instance.test_client()
    res = test_client.get("/admin")
    # Assert
    assert res.status_code == 200
```

The unit test itself worked fine and passed, however, it broke other unit tests and threw out error like

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.DetachedInstanceError: Instance <User at 0x115a78b90> is not bound to a Session; attribute refresh operation cannot proceed (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/bhk3)
```

Comment: At a _guess_, executing the `/admin` route is doing something with the session (committing perhaps?) that messes up the session / transaction setup in the test framework.

Comment: Maybe, let me mock the admin endpoint and try